Error in Transaction Simulation with Custom Solana Program: Invalid Account Data
Summary of the Problem
I'm working with a custom Solana program and encountering an error during the transaction simulation phase. The specific command I'm executing is intended to create extra metas using the Solana Program Library's transfer-hook example, but it fails with an error related to the transaction's account data.
Detailed Description and Research
The command I ran is as follows:
../../../target/debug/spl-transfer-hook create-extra-metas HookSNukpeokYkzRdKwK1d4LYMmNXGPkotw5cwqnwVyz TokkZcu8RTE46yWjF7LMTqqKa6LzTVM438qZDfz3qZH
And the error message I received is:
error: send transaction: error: send transaction: RPC response error -32002: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 1: invalid account data for instruction
I've already updated the main.rs file and the cargo.toml in the CLI folder, following suggestions to address a previous issue. After rebuilding with cargo build, this new error emerged.
What I’ve Tried
I ensured all updates were correctly applied to the source files and dependencies.
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/pull/6625
I searched for similar errors and found suggestions related to verifying account ownership and data initialization, but none of those solutions resolved my issue.
Ran the transaction in a controlled environment to isolate the error, confirming it specifically concerns how account data is handled or expected by the instruction processor.
Request for Help
Could anyone provide insights on why this error might be occurring with the account data during transaction simulation? Any advice on specific Solana patterns for account initialization or error handling in custom instructions would be greatly helpful. Additionally, if there are common pitfalls or debugging steps I might have overlooked, I'd appreciate guidance on those as well.

You'll need to make sure that HookSNukpeokYkzRdKwK1d4LYMmNXGPkotw5cwqnwVyz works as expected, and that TokkZcu8RTE46yWjF7LMTqqKa6LzTVM438qZDfz3qZH is an existing mint. Your transfer-hook program is the one failing, so you can run some tests on it to make sure that it works. It's hard to tell what's going on without more info unfortunately!
